# Converting JSon MetaData to R data.frame

Tags: json, r, dataframe, metadata

I need help transferring the meta-data from a list-form Json file (example sample of text below).

specifically I am having issues aligning every file as it seems to skip the null values, and defining the specific columns etc.

each data-set has somewhere around 80 parameters (md5sum, data_type.. etc..) of which around 20 or so have Null value but I still want them listed because of the 1000+ data set's the null values don't always coincide so when I have attempted to convert all the data into a data.frame I think they are jig-sawing around and not aligning well. 
hope this makes it a tiny bit clearer as to what I need.

Sample:

```
[{
  "md5sum": "aa", 
  "data_type": "bb", 
  "file_name": "cc", 
  "file_size": 100296, 
  "data_format": "BCR XML", 
  "submitter_id": null, 
  "access": "open", 
  "state": "live", 
  "file_id": "ee", 
  "data_category": "ff", 
  "associated_entities": [
    {
      "entity_id": "gg", 
      "case_id": "hh", 
      "entity_submitter_id": "II", 
      "entity_type": "case"
    }
  ],
```

some of the code attempts I've tried using but aren't really working:

```
library(rjson) 

jSnData2 <- fromJSON(file = "meta.json")

df <- lapply(jSonData2, function(play){ data.frame(matrix(unlist(play), ncol=66, byrow=T))})

df2 <- do.call(rbind, df)
```

Comment: sorry first time using this, ill try to make it more readable and understandable

Answer (score 0):

Use double brackets to select individual elements, then combine them into a dataframe.

I don't have RStudio on this computer to run this to test it so might have typos, but you should be able to use something like the following:

```
jSnData2 <- fromJSON(file='meta.json')
md5sum <- sapply(jSnData2, function(x) x[[1]])
data_type <- sapply(jSnData2, function(x) x[[2]])
#repeat for the rest of the elements in the json file

df <- data.frame(md5sum, data_type, #add all the other lists here)
```

Your result will be a dataframe with column names using whatever you called your lists.

Comment: ok so basically I pasted only a sub-section of my first data set, of which I have over 1000, each one containing around 80 "lists" as you said, md5sum etc etc.. that seems like a very long way of doing it no? either way I will try this regardless. thanks

Comment: You could write a loop and just set your column names using an array of names, there might be a way to extract those names but I don't know of it offhand.